# Upgrade message pop in Upsolver

Tags: upsolver

Sometimes we see a upgrade message on the UI screen. What does this mean and what happens on click of Upgrade vs Close? Is there any downtime during upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

These updates are only for UI cosmetic updates. If you click Upgrade button, it allows user to move to new UI version right away in current session. If you Close, it won't bring updated UI until user refreshes screen or closes and reopens. If user was not on the UI when update got pushed, user won't even see this message and would get the new version when the open the UI.

There is no real downtime for the UI update for reasons explained above. Even when there are backend changes, or changes to engine or API, those changes will have no real downtime. The deployment will happen outside business hours, plus we deploy to a new instance first and then transition to the new instance. So compute tasks etc won't get impacted.